# $x^3-px+q = 0$ how to solve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For what values $ p,q \in \mathbb R $ the equation $ x^3 - px + q= 0$ do you have 3 different solutions?

I tried $ f(x)=x^3+q $ and $g(x) = px $. Then $f(x), g(x) $ intersect at 3 points. But I didn't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: If the polynomial does not have three distinct solution, then it is of the form $(x-\alpha)^2 (x-\beta)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Your form is just a special case of $\left((x-\alpha)^2+\gamma^2\right)(x-\beta)$, in your form $\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $f(x)=x^3-qx+p$. Then $f'(x)=3x^2-q$. For $f$ to have three distinct roots, it cannot be that $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence $q>0$.

Let $r_1=-\sqrt{q/3}$ and $r_2=\sqrt{q/3}$. Then $f$ is decreasing on $[r_1,r_2]$ and increasing elsewhere. If $f$ is to have three distinct roots, the necessary and sufficient condition is that $f(r_1)>0$ and $f(r_2)<0$. This provides a restriction on $p$.